# Scheduling Pop Up Dialogue Box - Alarm?

Tags: task-management

Let's say Tuesday December 20, I need to leave the house at 10 AM. I'd like a pop-up notifier that reminds me (and stays on the screen until I've hit "ok"). What program works best for this?

Answer (score 1):

There are several methods to accomplish this from command line tools to calendars. What features are you looking for ?

Evolution has a notification system.

In Evolution Options -> Reminders

If that is not going to work out for you, please describe why not or what features you need/desire.

Comment: I use Thunderbird (so unfortunately Evolution doesn't work for me). The features I'm after are pretty simple:

1) Enter date/time, text of reminder. (Example: December 13, 2 PM. Leave for dentist appointment.)

2) Pop-up box comes up, in *front* of any windows I have open. It stays there until I've hit "ok". ("Alarm Clock" for Gnome fits most of my wants, but opens underneath the windows that are already there.)

I'm happy with a command line program, if there is one that fits the above requirements.

Thanks so much.

Comment: Oh! And if the computer wasn't on at the correct time, I'd be notified as soon as I turned the computer on again. (Not a necessity, but a great addition.)

Comment: Try kalarm. Most, if not all, of the command line options are going to require that the machine is on at the time.

Comment: Kalarm looks like it's definitely going to work for me, thanks so much. Do you know if there's a way to control where the display box pops up?

Comment: Aha - I found it, in the preferences. (There's even a "delay close button", which is perfect for me.)

Comment: You are most welcome.

Comment: Kalarm worked beautifully for ages, until I switched to Lubuntu and then the hotkey to open the program broke (for RSI reasons I use the keyboard as much as possible). Is there another good alternative?